# Spectral sequence for reduced homology

Tags: spectral-sequences, at.algebraic-topology

In the Serre spectral sequence, is it true that we can replace homology by reduced homology? That is:
If $f:X\rightarrow B$ is a Serre fibration,with $F$ the fiber, then if
$\tilde E^2_{pq}=\tilde H_p(B,\tilde H_q F)  \longrightarrow \tilde H_{p+q}(X)$?

I think it is fine: we use complexes involving "augmentation", then filtration, do the usual things in the spectral sequence, and finally we get a sequence that converges to the homology of the original complex. Only now it becomes reduced homology. But I am not precisely sure.

I ask this question because I want to know the answer of another problem (asked by me) "homology dimension of mapping class group of surface with boundary". (I am sorry I don't know how to insert a link). I need some help for that problem. Thanks!

Comment: Hint for the Serre spectral sequence: is the Kuenneth formula valid in reduced homology? (Work over a field and count dimensions.)

Comment: Hi,Tim Perutz, it is not valid. 

Comment: As Tim Perutz indicates, this version is not valid.  However, consider: for spaces with a chosen basepoint, reduced homology is isomorphic to homology relative to the basepoint.  For p: E -> B with subfibration D -> E, together with a subspace A of B, there is a Serre spectral sequence involving relative homology of the base and fiber, computing the homology of E relative to $D \cup p^{-1}A$.